# Docker Image with Mixin of Base Images

Tags: java, node.js, spring, angular, docker

I would like to build a docker image that uses NodeJs and Java Runtime.

It is possible to find separate docker files, one for each base.

How can I use two ***bases*** to create a new image?

In this case, i am gonna run a Angular App, and a Spring App in the same image.

Any tips on how to have a single image with such requirements? Does it make sense?

Comment: Can't you run three containers? node, java and the generated angular app? When you start to squeeze services together in one container there is normally something very wrong with the architecture. Ask yourself if it's possible to scale your app by running multiple instances of the container.

Comment: Very good point, I am in fact separating the two...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this makes sense in your case is hard to judge from the outside. In general should an image do one thing, run one app in particular. Seems like you are mixing two things in one container. If you really want to do this, I'd choose the "more difficult to install" image and choose it as a base image (seems to be the Spring image). Then I'd add the packages for node.js, which should only be a few lines of code. Since most Dockerfiles are public, you can look up the images and build your own image for both apps.

But in general this sounds like you really need two images, one for the Angular stuff, one for the Spring stuff. You can then compose these images with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) or manually by linking them if needed.

Comment: Sounds good! I agree with you, gonna have different images.

When I use the docker-compose, does it create a new images, or is it just for orchestrating containers?

Comment: @FilipeMiranda You can extend the images by using the `build` property in the service. The alternative is to just reference a pre-built image using `image` (common when build systems create the images instead).

Comment: docker-compose orchestrates and links the containers of your images. It automatically creates a network of your containers if you link them and mounts volumes if you want so. It is worth to try it out, I use it in nearly all my projects. `build` overwrites the `CMD` part of your Dockerfile, that's it. With `image` you can define your base image in the composition, which might be one of your two images. There are plenty examples for this on the Internet.